# Why is this an error with ERB?

Tags: ruby, erb

```
<div class='row'>
  <%= form.field_container :name do %>
    <%= form.label :name, raw('Name' + content_tag(:span, ' *', :class => 'required')) %>
    <%= form.text_field :name, :class => 'fullwidth' %>
    <%= form.error_message_on :name %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Why is this producing the following error?

```
$ erb -x -T - test.erb | ruby -c
-:3: syntax error, unexpected ')'
...form.field_container :name do ).to_s); _erbout.concat "\n"
...                               ^
-:9: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ')'
```

Comment: An important part of this question: this code [“renders on a Rails page”](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/issues/708), so it is not actually an error.

Comment: AFAIK Rails actually uses [erubis](http://rubygems.org/gems/erubis) so don't expect things to work quite the same way in Rails and plain erb.

Comment: another helping answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27465389/error-compiling-erb-code-from-string#answer-27469694

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you look at the code outputted by `erb -x -T - test.erb`:

```ruby
#coding:ASCII-8BIT
_erbout = ''; _erbout.concat "<div class='row'>\n  "
; _erbout.concat(( form.field_container :name do ).to_s); _erbout.concat "\n"
; _erbout.concat "    "; _erbout.concat(( form.label :name, raw('Name' + content_tag(:span, ' *', :class => 'required')) ).to_s); _erbout.concat "\n"
; _erbout.concat "    "; _erbout.concat(( form.text_field :name, :class => 'fullwidth' ).to_s); _erbout.concat "\n"
; _erbout.concat "    "; _erbout.concat(( form.error_message_on :name ).to_s); _erbout.concat "\n"
; _erbout.concat "  ";  end ; _erbout.concat "\n"
; _erbout.concat "</div>\n"
; _erbout.force_encoding(__ENCODING__)
```

You can see that on the third line, a `do` is followed by a `)`. Ruby is expecting a `do`…`end` block, but gets a closing parenthesis. That’s the immediate cause of the syntax error.

The reason for `erb` outtputting bad code is that you are using `<%=` when you should be using `<%`. Changing your code to this fixes the syntax error:

```erb
<div class='row'>
  <% form.field_container :name do %>
    <%= form.label :name, raw('Name' + content_tag(:span, ' *', :class => 'required')) %>
    <%= form.text_field :name, :class => 'fullwidth' %>
    <%= form.error_message_on :name %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I can’t run this code to test if it outputs what it should after my change, but the code generated by `erb` looks like it will work:

```ruby
#coding:ASCII-8BIT
_erbout = ''; _erbout.concat "<div class='row'>\n  "
;  form.field_container :name do ; _erbout.concat "\n"
; _erbout.concat "    "; _erbout.concat(( form.label :name, raw('Name' + content_tag(:span, ' *', :class => 'required')) ).to_s); _erbout.concat "\n"
# more...
```

### Edit

Since this solution apparently *does* break the output, I looked into what [mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short) suggested. I checked if [Erubis](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/erubis/), which [Rails 3 uses by default](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/erubis/users-guide.05.html), behaves differently from ERB. The code outputted by `erubis -x -T - test.erb` (with the original, unedited `test.erb`):

```ruby
_buf = ''; _buf << '<div class=\'row\'>
  '; _buf << ( form.field_container :name do ).to_s; _buf << '
'; _buf << '    '; _buf << ( form.label :name, raw('Name' + content_tag(:span, ' *', :class => 'required')) ).to_s; _buf << '
'; _buf << '    '; _buf << ( form.text_field :name, :class => 'fullwidth' ).to_s; _buf << '
'; _buf << '    '; _buf << ( form.error_message_on :name ).to_s; _buf << '
';   end 
 _buf << '</div>
';
_buf.to_s
```

Line three has the exact same problem, and `erubis -x -T - test.erb | ruby -c` outputs the same syntax error. So the differences between ERB and Erubis are probably not the problem.

I also tried syntax-checking this piece of code [from the official Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials):

```erb
<%= form_for(zone) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <b>Zone name</b><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

It gets the same syntax error. So it’s not that your ERB code is badly written; your code is very similar to that example.

At this point my best guess is that `erb`’s `-x` flag, which translates an ERB template into Ruby code instead of evaluating it directly, is flawed, and does not support some features it should. Though now that I think about it, I am having trouble imagining exactly what Ruby code *should* be outputted when you output the result of a block that itself outputs text should work. At what times should each of the outputs be written – the result first, or the block contents first?

Comment: @DanielFischer I wasn’t sure if `form.field_container` was supposed to return a value to output. Since you say it is, then `<%=` is indeed what you want, so the solution must be something else.

Answer (score 13):

Short version: nothing is wrong; Rails does some crazy stuff.

Long version: You can only do

```
<%= some_method do %>
<% end %>
```

(that is, use `<%=` with a block) because of a giant flying hack in Rails. The content of `<%=` `%>` is supposed to be an expression (or expressions) that stands on its own: you should be able to stick it into `eval` and have it be syntactically valid.

Before Rails 3, people were sometimes confused by the fact that with ‘normal helpers’ (`link_to`, `number_to_currency`, etc.), you had to use `<%=`, but when using the block form of these helpers or helpers like `form_for`, you had to use `<%`. That’s why Rails 3 made `<%=` support blocks.

To handle blocks in this case, when you use `<%=`, Rails looks at the ERB code, sees whether it looks like a block by using a regular expression, and if it does rewrites the generated code on the fly to turn it into valid Ruby.

More gory details in the excellent blog post “[Block Helpers in Rails 3](http://timelessrepo.com/block-helpers-in-rails3)”.