# Error compiling ERB code from string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, erb

I'm writing some tests for my view helper (Rails 4.0) and trying to compile ERB code in a string that executes it. However, for the sake of simplicity, I am using a common method found in the rails form helpers here and receiving the same error:

```
Failure/Error: ERB.new(template).result
SyntaxError:
  (erb):1: syntax error, unexpected ')'
  ...out.concat(( field_set_tag do ).to_s); _erbout.concat "\n\t\...
  ...                               ^
  (erb):4: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting ')'
  ; _erbout.force_encoding(__ENCODING__)
                                        ^
```

This is the code I'm executing:

```
template = <<-TEMPLATE
<%= field_set_tag do %>
    Lorem Ipsum
<% end %>
TEMPLATE

ERB.new(template).result
```

I've found some suggestions to use the `<%` instead of `<%=` but this results in `Lorem Ipsum` being the only output. I've also tried using HAML instead of ERB but came out with similar results.

How can I get my template to output `<fieldset>Lorem Ipsum</fieldset>` using the `field_set_for` helper inside a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“Normal” Eruby doesn’t allow for expressions using `<%=` to have blocks the way Rails uses them. Rails [extends the Erubis Eruby handler to add support for them](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.1.8/actionview/lib/action_view/template/handlers/erb.rb#L38-L47). Your test is just tring to use Erb directly, so this support isn’t available.

You need to make sure this support is loaded for this to work. I can get get it working with this:

```
ActionView::Template::Handlers::Erubis.new(template).evaluate(ActionView::Base.new)
```

I don’t know if this is the best way though. Check the RSpec docs, there may be a better way for testing parts of views like this.