# Compiled HAML code not as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, haml

I'm exploring using HAML as an alternative to ERB to potentially resolve this issue that I'm currently having in my Rails 4 tests: [Error compiling ERB code from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27465389/error-compiling-erb-code-from-string).

I'm executing the following code:

```
template = 
"= field_set_tag do\n" + 
"    Lorem Ipsum"

expected = '<fieldset>Lorem Ipsum</fieldset>'
actual = Haml::Engine.new(template).render(ActionView::Base.new).gsub("\n", '')    

expect(actual).to eq(expected)
```

And what I'm getting in my test result is:

```
Failure/Error: expect(actual).to eq(expected)

  expected: "<fieldset>Lorem Ipsum</fieldset>"
       got: "Lorem Ipsum<fieldset></fieldset>"
```

Why is the block "Lorem Ipsum" getting rendered before the fieldset tag? More importantly, how can I get it to render correctly?

Comment: Aren't you missing a print sign `=` at `Lorem Ipsum` line? It should be `   = Lorem Ipsum`

Comment: Nope, it's HAML so a line of plain text should be rendered as plain text.

Answer (score 1):

You haven’t got Haml correctly set up for use in Rails. Haml provides its own implementation of some Rails methods, including `capture` which is used by `field_set_tag`. Since this method isn’t loaded, the original `capture` is running and the block is output directly to the buffer but not captured.

The solution might be as simple as adding `require 'haml/template'`, but you should probably check the RSpec docs and make sure you are using it in the right way for Rails, I think `haml/template` should be loaded automatically.