# Why does this error with ERB occur?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to output some code from a database.

I created a table `Page` with columns `title` and `content`. In `content`, I put code for form. I am trying to output it in view.

```
<%= form_for :article do |f| %>
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :title, "Title" %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :price, "Price" %>
    <%= f.number_field :price, value: 1, class: 'form-control', min: 1 %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :stock, "Stock" %>
    <%= f.number_field :stock, value: 1, class: 'form-control', min: 1 %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
<% end %>
```

In my view, I have:

```
<% @pages.each do |page| %>
  <%= raw ERB.new(page.content).result(binding) %>
<% end %>
```

And I got an error:

```
(erb):1: syntax error, unexpected ')' t(( form_for :article do |f| ).to_s); _erbout.concat "\r\n<d ^ (erb):22: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')' ; end ; _erbout.force_encoding(__EN ^ (erb):22: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting ')' t.force_encoding(__ENCODING__) ^
```

I am stuck on this error. I assume that the error is in ERB, but I don't know how to fix it. It would be nice if you helped me.

Comment: This code looks fine. Must be some unbalanced parentheses in the rest of the file.

Comment: If I use <% form_for :article do |f| %> without "=", it will output inputs, but not a form

Comment: @Nikita <%= form_for :article do |f| %> `=` is used for displaying the form

Comment: Can you tell me which is line 22 in file ?

Comment: @Vishal, I know, but I'm getting the error

Comment: @Nikita Can you  give me line 22 in your file ?

Comment: @Vishal, I have updated post. In view I have only 3 lines.

Comment: @Nikita what is form file ? is it related to view ? can you just update the question with proper file name ?

Comment: Ruby can be quite annoying to debug. My goto strategy if all else fails is binary search :)
Comment out about half the code (with correct syntax) and if the error still exists, comment out the other half. Continue doing so until you find the line that actually causes the problem.

Comment: It something wrong with <%= form_for

Comment: @Nikita do you know the use of raw  ? it is used for parse html data, if you simple text you can use `<%=  page.content %>`, if you have html data than also you can directly use `<%= raw page.content %>` for parsing html

Comment: @Nikita can you just tell me which rails version are you using  ?

Comment: @Vishal I'm using ver. 5.1.6. What should I use if I have some rails code in database? I thought that it's erb.new

Comment: can you mention file names, it's confusing as you have two different view related code? filename and code will be fine

Comment: Actually, I don't understand some things. But if I use <%= render :inline => page.content %>, it works

Comment: @Nikita instead of form_for use form_with becasue form_for and form_tag is replaced with form_with in rails 5.1 `<%= form_with :article, local: true do |form| %>` try this. let me know if it is working

Comment: @Vishal the same error

Comment: @Nikita there is simple solution for overcome this issue, try to comment 2-2 lines and run page again, check in which 2 lines you are getting errors exactly, after you found that error. please let me know that lines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://timelessrepo.com/block-helpers-in-rails3 talks about this:

> `<%= box do %>` is simply not valid ERB. While there’s no written spec
>   for ERB, there are some basic rules which every implementation of ERB
>   can follow.
>
> The first rule is that the expression in `<%= =%>` must be a complete
>   expression. A complete expression is an expression which you can
>   pass directly into eval without getting a syntax error. Or you could
>   say that it’s a piece of Ruby code which you can place parenthesis
>   around and it still ends up as valid Ruby:
>
> ```
> eval("f.text_field")  # => Works fine 
> ( f.text_field )      # => Valid
>
> eval("box do")        # => SyntaxError
> ( box do )            # => Invalid
> ```
>
> The expression in `<% %>` on the other hand only needs to be a
>   subexpression. A subexpression is something which by itself is an
>   invalid expression, but becomes valid if there’s another subexpression
>   below or above it which completes it. You could also say that it’s a
>   piece of Ruby code which you can place semicolons around:
>
> ```
> eval("box do")    # => SyntaxError
> ; box do ;        # => Valid (as long as there is an `end` later)
> ```
>
> As you can see, `box do` is a
>   subexpression, but not a complete expression. Therefore, in normal
>   ERB, you can put it inside `<% %>`, but not `<%= %>`.

And indeed, if you go into your ERB.new(page.content) object, you'll see it starts by trying to do this:

```
#coding:UTF-8
_erbout = ''; 
_erbout.concat(( form_for :article do |f| ).to_s);
```

So it complains because it doesn't know how to evaluate the expression `form_for :article do |f|` by itself.

Rails does special processing behind the scenes to make these work when it does its own rendering, but it's not something that comes from ERB.

(Similar issue: [Why is this an error with ERB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17374274/why-is-this-an-error-with-erb) )